# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4

Tags: flutter

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════ RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 what does it mean,the code is fine [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HakLR.jpg)

i am learning flutter and  i got this error ,can someone explain me why i got this error

Comment: Please **DO NOT** attach images of code. They cannot be copy/pasted, indexed by search engines, and can be blocked by filters. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add your code as formatted text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035), along with [this website](//idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests you're accessing an index (4) outside the valid range (0 to 3). Make sure that  index is within bounds.

In Dart and many programming languages, list indices start at 0. This means that the first element in a list has an index of 0, the second element has an index of 1, and so on. If you have a list like [1, 2, 3], the elements are at indices 0, 1, and 2.

E.g

```
List<int> numbers = [1, 2, 3];/// 0,1,2

// Incorrect usage that leads to RangeError
// int value = numbers[4];

// Correct usage with a check
int index = 4; // from 0 to 2 will pass as correct
if (index >= 0 && index < numbers.length) {
  int value = numbers[index];
  print(value);
} else {
  print("Index $index is out of bounds");
}
```

Comment: thankyou brother got it fixed  i used if condition to check the index

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck and keep on!