# RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 1

Tags: flutter, dart

The following IndexError was thrown building Builder:

```
RangeError (index): Index out of range: no indices are valid: 1
The relevant error-causing widget was:
MaterialApp MaterialApp:/lib/main.dart:14:12
```

[image]

I am using Flutlab, does anyone know how to solve this error?

Comment: Please donot write link of the screenshot instead copy and paste the code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for your problem I answered few days ago

[RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..3: 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049745/rangeerror-index-invalid-value-not-in-inclusive-range-0-3-4/78050751#78050751)